# SQL Data storage

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySQL database which stores data next way:

```
 id   |   value  |
 1       @value1 
         @value2 
         @value3 
_________@value4__
 2       @value5 
         @value6 
_________@value7__ 
 3       @value8 
         @value9
```

In case if I would need to extract the "value" from particular "id" I proceed with next steps:

- SELECT an "id" row I would need
- using the php function `explode("@",$value)` make a cutting of the values that are stored within particular "id" and create an array from it.

So my question would be is it efficient to work and store data this way? Maybe I should change the way of storing (as below) and use only SQL queries to retrieve the data.

What would you recommend?

```
 id   |   value  |
 1       @value1 
 1       @value2 
 1       @value3 
_1_______@value4__
 2       @value5 
 2       @value6 
_2_______@value7__ 
 3       @value8 
 3       @value9
```

Comment: Tables in RELATIONAL databases are built upon PRIMARY KEYs. They're what establish the RELATION. If you don't have a PRIMARY KEY, then you don't have a table.

Answer (score 1):

Change your schema to:

```
id | group | value
======================
1  | 1     | "Value 1"
2  | 1     | "Value 2"
3  | 1     | "Value 3"
4  | 2     | "Value 4"
5  | 2     | "Value 5"
6  | 3     | "Value 6"
7  | 3     | "Value 7"
8  | 3     | "Value 8"
...
```

This way each row has a unique ID, which is very useful if you find yourself in a situation where you need to point to a specific row, and the values will be grouped using an identifier (a number in this case).

Now you can easily select all the values that belong to a certain group:

```
SELECT `value` FROM `tableName` WHERE `group` = 2
```

That will give you this subset of the table:

```
id | group | value
======================
4  | 2     | "Value 4"
5  | 2     | "Value 5"
```

The SQL to create the table is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tableName`;

CREATE TABLE `tableName` (
    `id`    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `group` INT NOT NULL,
    `value` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);
```

You should also read up on what the [relational model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) is, and how it works. Knowing how to [normalize your database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is a related topic, which is useful to know about.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking about but why this way of storing is better then that I am using at this moment?

Comment: It is better because data should just be data. Storing data as strings that need to be manipulated in order to be used defeats the purpose of using a database. You should read about the [relational model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) if you want to understand how relational databases work. It is a huge topic that I am not able to explain here.